# Cross Compile OpenCV Cannot Find libv4l1

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, arm, ubuntu-12.04, cross-compiling

I am following tutorial from [this](http://linuxandstuff.blogspot.com/2012/05/cross-compiling-opencv-for-mini6410arm.html) blog about cross compiling opencv for ARM.
My host system is Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit and compiler is gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi 4.5.1.

When running make, I get the following error

```
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_createsamples
[ 98%] Building CXX object apps/haartraining/CMakeFiles/opencv_createsamples.dir/createsamples.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_createsamples
/usr/local/arm/4.5.1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.5.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lv4l1
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_createsamples] Error 1
make[1]: *** [apps/haartraining/CMakeFiles/opencv_createsamples.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It seems like opencv is looking for libv4l1. Doing aptitude search, I found out that in my machine I have installed libv4l and libv4l2. In [this web](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+package/libv4l-dev), I found that libv4l1 is deprecated for Ubuntu 12.04. Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Instead of compiling libv4l for the ARM and create make file using cmake-gui, I use cmake files found in /platforms/linux/
Please see [Open CV page](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/crosscompilation/arm_crosscompile_with_cmake.html) for the cross compilation details.

Note: I change the cmake files so that instead of looking for arm compiler installed in my system, it looks for arm compiler toolchain provided for my target board (mini6410) by setting the CMAKE_C_COMPILER, CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER, and ARM_LINUX_SYSROOT varibles

The OpenCV library works, I can convert image from RGB to grayscale on the target board, and save the gray image to a .jpg file, view the image in my host computer

Answer (score 0):

You will need libv4l1 for the target environment. The libv4l1  for your machine is of no use.